# Can i send a variable from event handler as prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

suppose my code is:

```
export default function test(){
    let a;
    let b;
    function handleEvent() {
        a = 2;
        b = 5;
    }
    return(
        <>
        <Testing a={a} b={b} />
        </>
    )
}
```

can i pass **a** and **b** as prop to a component?

Is all event handler independent? I mean can i use its variables outside of it?

Comment: That is not the way it is supposed to be done in React. You are normally expected to keep track of `a` and `b` within your state (e.g. `[a, setA] = useState(<--initial value of 'a'-->)`) and update it within `handleEvent()` body (using `setA(<---new value of A-->)`) so, that it becomes available to `<Testing />` component as a prop.

Comment: i did not set it in state because i don't want it to change in every render. i want its value will be fixed in initial rendering, can't i assign value in it in event handler?

Comment: You may set the value just once (e.g. setting initial value to `null` and doing `a && setA('newA')` in the `handleEvent()` body).

Answer (score 0):

If you need call it inside the child(ren) component(s) you can pass it to that/them:

```js
function App() {
  const renderRoot = React.useRef(0);
  console.log('root renders:', ++renderRoot.current);
  const [v,setV]=React.useState({a:0,b:0});
  const changeV= React.useCallback((v)=>{
    setV(v);
  },[]);
  

  return (<MyChild a={v.a} b={v.b} changeV={changeV}/>)
}

function MyChild({a,b, changeV}) {
   const myChildRenders = React.useRef(0);
   console.log('my child renders:', ++myChildRenders.current);
   
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const myInterval = setInterval(()=>changeV({a: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1), b: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)}),2000);
    return ()=>clearInterval(myInterval);
  },[]);
  
   return <div>
      <p>a is : {a}</p>
      <p>b is : {b}</p>
   </div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```